# What does non-combinational area represent in synopsys design compiler

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, synthesis

I have designed a ripple adder using full adders. In order to find delay incurred to perform this addition I included a clock in each full adder module. In my main code I instantiated these modules to construct the ripple adder. When I synthesised the ripple adder code and found the area the result was something like :

```
combinational area=54
non-combinational area=204;
```

I want to know if this non-combinational area is due to overhead of including clock in each module. Is there any way to reduce this non-combinational area.

Comment: Post Verilog please - also, isn't it normally PrimeTime you should be using to find delay?

Comment: i used timing_report command in design compiler. I used create_clock command to give period of the clock.

Answer (score 1):

Non-combinational area is generally just the size of the sequential elements in your design (flip flops, latches, rams, etc). Did you include any of these when you created the clocks?

Comment: check your netlist. While you may not have intended to have sequential elements, design compiler may have thought you did.

Comment: @ tim i gave 'and' operation and xor operation inside always block to design halfadder. Does that come under non-combinational area?

Comment: module haa59(a,b,s,c,clk);
input a,b; 
input clk;
output s,c;
reg c1,s1;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    
    s1<=a^b;
   
 c1<=a&&b;
end
assign s=s1;
 assign c=c1;

    endmodule

Comment: the above is halfadder verilog code which i used to design full adders.

Comment: That module has two flip flops in it (s1 and c1). Those will both count for non-comb. area. The `and` and `xor` are combinational area. @twinkle

Comment: As i have given s1 and c1 in always block will they be considered as registers?

Comment: @twinkle - Not necessarily, you could have a combinational always block as well. They are synthesized as registers because you have them updating their values on posedge of the clock (that's what registers do, update on clock edge)

Comment: @tim Is there anyother way to clock the module other than using always block?

Comment: I do not know what you think 'clock the module' really means. Clocks exist so that they can drive sequential elements. A pure combinational circuit should not have a clock. @twinkle

Comment: @tim If i have a big combinational block and i want to find the critical path delay ,how do i go about?

Comment: @twinkle - Sorry I do not know the answer. Perhaps that would be a good topic for a question.